# How to set Status bar under transparent view when UIAlertController appears in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am working on `UIAlertController`. Here when Alert appears we can see the transparent background. But status bar doesn't come under this transparent. Please look the image, the status bar is still visible.

[image]

My Code for `UIAlertController` is:

```
func showAlert(title: String, message: String,btnsText: [String], tag:String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alertController.accessibilityLabel = tag
    for i in 0 ..< btnsText.count {
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: btnsText[i], style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:
                {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in self.delegate?.AlertCompleted!(title: alert.title!,tag: alertController.accessibilityLabel!)}))
    }
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: Did you solve this issue yet?